# Angular Material ngModel on md-select not binding

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an angular material select bound to `appraisalPeriod` variable in my class:

```
<md-select placeholder="Select Appraisal Period" class="custom-select" id="appraisalPeriod" name="appraisalPeriod" [(ngModel)]="appraisalPeriod" (ngModelChange)="onApprisalChange($event)" floatPlaceholder="never">
     <md-option *ngFor="let period of appraisalPeriodList | keys" [value]="period.key">{{period.value}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

One example of period:{"201707":"2017Q2"}

I have an emitter in my `.ts` file:

```
this.emitterGoalsheet.subscribe(goalSheet => {
   this.appraisalPeriod = goalSheet.appraisal_id;
   alert(this.appraisalPeriod);
 });
```

However, when the `appraisalPeriod` property is fetched (as is known from the alert box that is displayed), the select box value does not update itself and remains empty.

Additional information:
`keys.pipe.ts` file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({  name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
    const keys = [];
    for ( const key in value ) {
      if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
      }
    }
    return keys;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you declared appraisalPeriod in scope?

Comment: Yes. It is declared as string: `appraisalPeriod: string;`

Comment: Then write `this.$scope.appraisalPeriod="goalSheet.appraisal_id"`

Comment: I am coding in angular 4. So think this should work: `this.appraisalPeriod = goalSheet.appraisal_id;`

Comment: Oops yeah I noticed the tag later